# Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'. > Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-studio, syntax-error, android-layoutparams

What is the problem, can anyone help me, I am working on the WhatsApp stickers application

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\Aged\Desktop\ssssssssss\stickers-master\stickers-master\Android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlZ7s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Player Settings/Publishing Settings` and enable the Custom Base Gradle Template option after that go to `<Project>/Assets/Plugins/Android` folder open and edit baseprojecttemplate, change the version of the Gradle plugin 3.4.0 to 3.4.3

```
buildscript {
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3'
       }
   }
```